# How to consume SSRS locally in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have gone through many links but now I need someone who can assist me better. Neither I have experience in hosting and nor in SSRS.

Following few sites, I added Business Intelligence->"Reporting project" from visual studio in my already existing Asp.net MVC app. Then I have successfully created two rdl reports which I can preview very well. Now the question is to consume them in asp.net application?

Steps I did is:

1) Opened IIS and created a new website with Physical directory to "Path of my 
   SSRS project". I can now see that location if I Explore this website from 
   IIS.

2) Now coming to asp.net code. I have already added basic code which is required to view a report but problem is the "Path". Do I have to define "Local server path" or "Remote". What is the difference between both. Does they require physical location of that rdl file. If it requires physical location, then how can I will get that because the rdl file is in different project and it is not present in my main webapp. I am confused with this. sometime i get error in if I try to give my application path. And for below code it is showing me this error.

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'reportserver'

Here is the project structure:

[image]

This is what I have in controller

```
    ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer
        {
            ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote
        };

        //reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath =
        //    Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) +
        //    "~/Reports/Report3.rdl";

        //reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.GetFullPath("~/ReportingProject/Reports/Report3.rdl");
        //reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine("~/ReportingProject/Reports/Report3.rdl");

        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://ReportServer/Reports/report3.rdl");


        //string solutiondir = Directory.GetParent(
        //    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
        //// may need to go one directory higher for solution directory
        //return XDocument.Load(solutiondir + "\\" + ProjectBName + "\\Mock\\myDoc.html")

        reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);


        reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new
            ReportDataSource("DataSet1", objList));

        reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();

        ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
```

Comment: You need to use the `ReportServer URL`, not the `Reports URL`. `http://servername/ReportServer/report3.rdl` If you don't have the rdl extension in the Reports Manager, then you don't need it in the URL string.

Comment: It will not work even after doing this.

 reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/reportserver/report3.rdl");

The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'. The request failed with an empty response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the SOAP reporting service (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.aspx) to get the report you want using ListChildren() method with the path of the parent folder (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren.aspx).